# Is it possible to label duplicate records in a MySQL update statement?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, duplicates, updates

I have a CSV import into a `temp_import_table` in which I'm validating the imported data before commiting to the database (`mysql 5.0.88`).

I'm trying to search the records in the validation table for duplicate entries, but I can't get it to work like this:

```
<cfquery datasource="#session.datasource#">
    UPDATE import_pricat_csv
    SET err = "ja", errtxt = "duplicate EAN"
    WHERE iln = <cfqueryparam value="#Session.logId#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="16">
        AND ean IN (
            SELECT ean
            FROM import_pricat_csv
            GROUP BY ean
            HAVING COUNT(ean) > 1
            )
</cfquery>
```

This throws an error:

```
You can't specify target table 'import_pricat_csv' for update in FROM clause
```

**Question:**
Is this not possible? Is there a better way than to loop once to get duplicates and a second time to set dup-records to `err="yes"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the multiple-table `UPDATE` syntax to join with the materialised group results:

```
UPDATE import_pricate_csv NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT ean FROM import_pricate_csv GROUP BY ean HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t SET
  import_pricate_csv.err    = 'ja',
  import_pricate_csv.errtxt = 'duplicate EAN'
;
```

Comment: ah. Never heard of this. Trying and hoping this works in `5.0.88`. Thanks!

Comment: Perfect! Did not think it was possible. Thanks again!